# Setter for a dynamic component property Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with Dynamic component creating ( resolveComponentFactory )
so it's working good with static @Input() properties. But for dynamic setter it isn't working.

I can't do that `this.componentReference.instance[myPropVar]= someValue`
with setter that created inside component.

Is it possible? Thanks!

property setter in my dynamic component is:

```
 @Input() set lockMessage(val: any) {
    if (val) {
      console.log("Visit details -> ", val);

    }
  }
```

it is the same like in that post
[Angular 2 dynamic component creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39079161/angular-2-dynamic-component-creation)

but I want to add some property which have setter to my dynamically created component.

P.S.  yes. I tried to set my property to dynamic component with that construction

```
  /**
     * public updateSingleComponentProp -> update single prop on component instance
     * @param prop {string} -> property name
     * @param val {any} -> property value
     * @returns {void}
     */
    public updateSingleComponentProp(prop: string, val: any): void {
        let compInstance = this.componentReference.instance;

      compInstance[prop] = val;

        if (compInstance.hasOwnProperty(prop) || compInstance.hasOwnProperty('_' + prop))
            compInstance[prop] = val;
        else
            throw new Error("Component doesn't have this property -> " + prop);

    }
```

and it throws an error because that property doesn't exists. I checked the component instance and  that setter exists in prototype

Comment: Could you give a [mcve] that demonstrates what you're trying to do?

Comment: I don't see why this would be a problem. `myPropVar` is a string that matches the name of the property (`lockMessage`), right? You don't need `@Input()` if you access it only imperatively. Do you get an error message?

Comment: Yes, I updated my post

Comment: So what's the error it throws?

Comment: Can you try what happens if you make the setter a function and use it like `this.componentReference.instance[myPropVar](someValue)`

Comment: Component doesn't have this property lockMessage (because it is in prototype setter)

Comment: I tried to use
compInstance = this.componentReference.instance  **compInstance[prop](val);** and I got an error: 
 **TypeError: compInstance[prop] is not a function(…)**

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` doesn't work if you just have `public myPropVar: string;` inside your component. The property isn't initialised  yet, so it will always return false in runtime.

Comment: yes, I know that. So I just tried to do all stuff that was described above without validations.

Comment: If nobody knows a correct answer so I'll try to do it via rx.j services. Thanks everybody